# window.open() not working when the file location is within a subfolder

Tags: javascript, php

I am quite new to programing so I apologize for any blatant ignorance, but, I can't find this answer.

I am using `window.open()` to open a `.php` file in a popup and passing a variable within the URL for use with `$_GET`.

Everything works fine when the `.php` page file I am opening is located in my main directory, for example:

> window.open("../filetoopen.php?link="+variable, ...)

But, when I move `filetoopen` into a different subfolder and change the path, the webpage will not load.
example:

> window.open("../subfolder/filetoopen.php/link="+variable, ...)

Just as a side note, I am working on a web app that has been developed by multiple people over several years and have only just begun familiarizing myself with its inner workings.

Any insight/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe its a typo? `../subfolder/filetoopen.php/link=` you mean `../subfolder/filetoopen.php?link=`

Comment: I can't think of any reason this would happen other than "The URL is wrong" and we have no way to telling, based on the information in the question, what the right URL is (or if it exists at all).

Comment: Try using an absolute path instead of a relative path: `window.open("/pathfrom/doc_root/to/filetoopen.php?link="+variable)`. It makes things a lot saner.

Comment: Maybe you can implement absolute paths. Using absolute paths in the correct manner will prevent you of getting so many headaches

Comment: Lawrence, yes thank you there was a type above, I approved the edit, however there wasn't in my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue:

There was another .php file located in the root directory which was needed to be referenced for the page to load.
example:
include 'utils.php';
And, when I moved the file within the subfolder, I did not change the path of the other file as well.
example:
include '../utils.php';

Thank you for all your responses.